# How do we handle password change and password forgotten and token refresh?

Tags: django-rest-framework, jwt, django-authentication

This has been a really great set of tutorials at Thinkster.io. I've been able to take this approach to the backend and create a Vue front end to consume the API. However, how do we handle token refresh and password management? I wanted to make sure I haven't missed anything in https://thinkster.io/tutorials/django-json-api/authentication

Specifically, I'm looking for the following use cases:
When/how to refresh tokens
Update password - I'm guessing I can do that in the update serializer
Forgotten password - Should I tie this all the way back to the Django Auth reset?

Any suggestions on next steps would be great